# Post parameter gets null value mvc4 web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
 [ActionName("Doctor")]
        public void Post(Doctor doctor)
        {
            exManager.Process(() => DoctorContext.CreateNewDoctor(doctor), "ANE");
        }
```

Doctor object is send from postman

```
  http://localhost:50667/api/Doctor/Doctor
    Content-Type application/json
    {"DoctorId":0,"DoctorName":"girish","Specialist":"demotology","Patients":[],"Presriptions":[],"Clinics":[],"Contact"{"ContactId":0,"Address":"tumkur","State":"karnataka","Country":"India","PinNumber":1234,"PhoneNumber":97432,"Email":"girish.ggt@gmail.com"}}
```

before is working right.. after applying enterterprice library.. it getting null..